# SED word ending with a letter and deleting that letter

Tags: unix, sed

Trying to do a unix shell script that takes input from a file that has one word per line, find any word that  ends with the letter s and removes that letter.

```
Input:
Glass
Faces
Passed
Hello
Tests
Pass

Output
Glas
Face
Test
Pas
```

I dont even mind if the out put still contains words that didn't end with s. I can work with that.

So far I've got

```
cat $1 | sed -e '/\s$/N; s/\(.*\)./\1/;'
```

But this is removing the last letter in EVERY word, not only the ones ending with s.

I'm new to unix and programming in general and must admit the syntax is still very hard for me to get right. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What would be the code if I also want to keep the wprds that didn't match the search criteria? So it would find the words ending with s and remove the s, but the output will include all words not ending with s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
sed -e '/s$/!d' -e 's/s$//'
```

Or this:

```
sed '/s$/!d;s/s$//'
```

Or this:

```
sed -n '/s$/{s/s$//;p;}'
```

Comment: Thank you, the first example you provided works great. can you explain a part the first code to me? I understand the second part as substituting 's' with nothing. But what does !d mean?


I'm very new and would like to understand the syntax instead of just getting awesome people to give me the answers :)

Comment: @user2661167: `/s$/` means "if it has 's' at the end", `/s$/!` means "if it *doesn't* have 's' at the end", and the `d` means "delete".

Comment: so if i wanted to keep the words that don't end with s in the out put I would use sed -e '/s$//'   ??

Comment: @user2661167: Try it.